# Derivation of equation of cone passing through the feet of normal of a conicoid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I am posting three pictures from my text book regarding the derivation of the equation of cone which has the 6 normals from a point on a conicoid as its generators

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have posted the derivation from the very definition of normal , since the text uses equation derived from previous proofs . I have the following questions

> 1.While deriving the equation of the Quadric cone how did the author eliminate $r $ from the equations
>   $\frac{af/l}{1+ar}=\frac{bg/m}{1+br}=\frac{ch/n}{1+cr} $(I have marked
>   it with three questions marks)
>
> 2.Why is it necessary to even study about the number of normals drawn from a given point to a conicoid and the equation of the cone having
>   these normals as generators

Answer (score 0):

Set: $A=af/l$, $B=bg/m$, $C=ch/n$, and rewrite your equations as
$$
{1+ar\over A}={1+br\over B}={1+cr\over C}.
$$
To eliminate $r$, use the first equation to find
$$
r={A-B\over aB-bA}
$$
and plug that into the second equation:
$$
C\left(1+b{A-B\over aB-bA}\right)=B\left(1+c{A-B\over aB-bA}\right).
$$
Simplify to get the stated result.